# Why is my inequality test failing?

Tags: php

The ever flaky Xdebug is on the fritz at the mo' (normal service will be resumed as soon as possible), so I am reduced to "debug by echo".

```
echo($path_info['filename'] . '    ' . $licence['issue_timestamp'].'<br>');      
if ($path_info['filename'] != $licence['issue_timestamp'])
{  
die('They are NOT equal');
   $_SESSION['error_messages'][] = 'This licence file has been copied';
   return False;
}
else   
die('They are equal');
```

outputs

```
1319266557_   1319266557
They are equal
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?  Is there something special about (trailing) underscores?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) state:

> `$a != $b     Not equal   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.`

And that "type juggling" looks mighty suspicious. Elsewhere on that page, it mentions:

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is `===` or `!==` as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

And the example is a dead giveaway as to what's happening in your case:

> `var_dump(100 == "1e2"); // 100 == 100 -> true`

In terms of how strings are converted to integers, that can be seen [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion). The salient bit is (my bold):

> If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E' and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other cases it will be evaluated as a float.
>
> The value is given by the **initial** portion of the string.
>
> Example: `$foo = 1 + "10 Small Pigs";       // $foo is integer (11)`

That's why "123_" is equal to "123" <sup>(a)</sup>. Bottom line, use `!==` since that ensures both the value and the type are the same.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> See the [online PHP executor](http://www.functions-online.com/intval.html):
[image]

Comment: That would only work if you're female and could somehow convince my wife that it's a good idea. While the first is possible, I can't see the second one _ever_ eventuating :-)

Comment: It's the thought that counts ;-)  (don't reckon my wife would go for it either ;-)

Answer (score 3):

One of the bone-headed things that PHP does is that [`==` only compares values "after type juggling"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).  What this means is that what most sane people think of as `==` is really `===` in PHP.  Try

```
$path_info['filename'] !== $licence['issue_timestamp'].
```

Comment: 1 sorry, one minute after the other post, so he gets the answer. Thanks, though.